# Copy from Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel file and I need to copy data from one column. But I don't know how many rows are there.

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook _workBook = xlApp.Workbooks;
    Excel.Worksheet _workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet) _workBook.Worksheets[1];
```

How can I copy data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range range = _workSheet .UsedRange;

int rows = range.Rows.Count;
int cols = range.Columns.Count;

// nested loops to take values from used range of cell one by one
for(int r=1; r <= rows; r++)
    for(int c=1; c <= cols; c++)
        object cellValue = range.Cells[r,c].Value2;

// take values from one row
int row = 1;
for(int c=1; c <= cols; c++)
    object cellValue = range.Cells[row,c].Value2;
```

Comment: And how can I paste `cellValue` to another sheet?

Comment: something like this: ((Excel.Range)anotherWorkSheet.Cells[r, c]).Value2 = cellValue;

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't provide any information about the library you are using for working with excel, i will assume you are using Interop Services:

```
int columns = _workSheet.Columns.Count;
int rows = _workSheet.Rows.Count;
int cells = columns*rows
string cellValue = (string)((Excel.Range)_workSheet.Cells[1, 1]).Value;
```